# Generate multiple files based on file templates

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13

Is it possible to add a script (run in IntelliJ) that adds multiple files based on the defined file templates?

**Use Case**:

I am working on an enterprise Java project that uses spring, hibernate, ..
For every Hibernate mapping, there are certain files that need to be created:

- hibernate mapping with name `[mappingName]`
- [mappingName]Repository
- [mappingName]RepositoryImpl
- [mappingName]Service
- [mappingName]ServiceImpl
- [mappingName]Controller
- [mappingName]LinkBuilder
- [mappingName]DTO
- [mappingName]DTOMapper

I created file templates for all these files, but instead of creating every file manually, i would like to create them all in bulk.

It doesn't really matter which scripting language :-)

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
[Creating and Editing Multi-File Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates__Multifile.html)

Comment: I also did find that page, but unfortunately this only applies to ReSharper and not IntelliJ